# how to delete one number in R

Tags: r

As the image shows, I calculate the pt value and rank it. Then I used which function to find the index of the largest value pt. Since there are two values of 1, I need to find the first index, so I use min function, and it does give me value of 4. Then I want to delete the 4th value in pt, and I suppose to see 0.85, 0.713, 0.666, and 1, because I only want to delete one number. However, it somehow deletes two number stead. What is the reason, and how can I fix it?

[image: sample code]

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Don't post code as an image. If you just want to delete item `i`, then do `pt[-i]`

Comment: Your last line calls all elements in pt that are NOT equal to pt[i]. That is all elements that are not pt[4] which is 1.0. This is why it returns everything but 1.0. MrFlick is correct

Answer (score 2):

After `i` is calculated, just do

```
pt <- pt[-i]
```

Then type `pt` in the console and you will have the desired output.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22162487)

Comment: @ChrisGong - yes it does.  We have a new contributor who didn't properly format the code.  Fixed now :)

Comment: PS - you can hit the "edit" button and see how I formatted the code.  And there is a link to markdown help in the upper right corner of the editing box.

Comment: @RichScriven my apologies, this was definitely a mistake on my part